# Prawn can't find locally stored image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

I'm trying to render a locally stored image to PDF using Prawn. This is what I'm doing in my class ..

```
def to_pdf
    cover = book.cover_url
    text cover
    image cover
    render
end
```

.. expecting it to render the image path, then the image itself. But what I'm getting is an ArgumentError which gives me back the path, "/system/images/image.jpg not found", that does in fact show me the image when I paste it in the address bar. `book.cover_url` outputs a relative path as a string. This path is correct - if I use the same code in a view, the image is shown.

This also doesn't work:

```
cover = "#{Rails.root}#{book.cover_url}"
image cover
```

This gives me a similar error (as expected):

```
cover = "#{Rails.root}#{book.cover_url}"
image open(cover)
```

However this does work:

```
cover = "http://localhost/system/images/image.jpg"
image open(cover)
```

As does this:

```
cover = "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41EPYSumZvL._SX329_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg"
image open(cover)
```

Prawn just can't seem to find the image using the path it's provided with. It's driving me nuts. Judging from the documentation, this should all be very straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

`Rails.root` gives you the file path where your rails application is located on the file system - this has nothing to do with the URL to a file. You should instead rewrite your `.cover_url` to provide and absolute URL and create a `.cover_path` method which outputs a relative path. (This is more consistent with the way path and asset helpers work in rails.)

If your image is available through the assets pipeline you would use [`url_to_image`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-url_to_image).